# How the progress bar of Git Hub app is implemented

Tags: android, progress-bar, progressdialog

When I was trying to implement the progress bar. I came across the git hub application
which implements fabulous progress bar spinner. I was just curious how do they do it.
How they are calling spinner in app such way other part of activiy UI loads but
Part of activity ie one probabalyfetched from server shows spinner.
Since Git hubis open source software I was able to browse the code. But I couldnt undrstand much.

[GiHub App Source Code](https://github.com/github/android/tree/master/app)
Anyone who know how they are implementing the progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a regular `ProgressBar` with a custom style. E.g.

https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/res/layout/progress_dialog.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_loading"
    style="@style/Spinner"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp" />
```

Defines that it should use the `Spinner` style which is defined as

https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="Spinner">
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/spinner</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDuration">2000</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">true</item>
</style>
```

That style defines a custom drawable to be used which is defined as a two part [LayerList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList).

https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/res/drawable/spinner.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_inner"/>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="360" >
            <bitmap
                android:antialias="true"
                android:filter="true"
                android:src="@drawable/spinner_outer" />
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

The [inner image](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/res/drawable-nodpi/spinner_inner.png) is the cat logo, the [outer images](https://github.com/github/android/blob/master/app/res/drawable-nodpi/spinner_outer.png) that is set to rotate 360° is the dashed circle.

Comment: Great Thanks zapl :) !! I also did find this info along with that how they are calling spinner in app such way other part of activiy UI loads but part of activity ie one probabalyfetched from server shows spinner.